# Why space of polynomials not complete while $\ell^\infty$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$\ell^\infty$ is complete under the metric

$$d(a,b)=\sup_{i}|a_i-b_i|$$

, but the following normed space $X$ of polynomial is not complete

$$\| x \|= \max_j |\alpha_j|$$, where for a polynomial of degree $N_x$,
we write $x(t)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \alpha_j t^j$,
   ($\alpha_j=0$ for $j>N_x$)

I know how to prove the completeness of the first space and incompleteness of the second space.

But it still feels weird, because two spaces are quite similar.

I would appeciate it if someone can give a **concrete example** of Cauchy Sequence in $X$, that does not converge.

Because my proof is based on uniform boundedness theorem, without explicitly construct non-converging Cauchy sequence.

Comment: How about, $1,1+x,1+x+{x^2\over2!}, 1+x+{x^2\over2!}+{x^3\over3!},\dots$?

Comment: Thanks! This is a great example.

Comment: An easy way to show that $e^x$ restricted to any real interval $(a,b)$ with $a<b,$ is not a polynomial on that interval, is that for a polynomial $P$ of degree $n$, the $(n+1)$th derivative of $P$ is $ 0 $ but $e^x$ is its own derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that polynomials correspond to the set of all sequences that are eventually zero, which is a linear subspace in $\ell^\infty$ that is not closed, and hence not complete. (In fact this is true regardless of which $p$-norm one chooses.)

As an explicit example, consider the polynomials $p_n(t) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} t^j/j^2$, the sequence of which converges to a (formal) power series, and not a polynomial.